# Log all URLs visited by user windows machine within a windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, browser-history, packet-capture, web-traffic

I've been searching the internet for C# tutorials on how to implement a windows service that sits on a windows machine that logs all URLs visited from any browser on that machine. In the most simple sense i literally want to Log the URL and DateTime to a text file.

All the posts I've found are around or over 10 years old so i'm not sure if they are still viable and many include using 3rd party libraries such as winPcap,Pcap, FiddlerCore which seem over kill for what i'm after.

In the simplest sense, I don't want to monitor all my network traffic, i don't want to intercept and manipulate packets or install some underlying proxy server and i don't care about request times and packet sizes.

Is the above possible without have to use a third party library like winPcap? Is there some kind event listener available the can be subscribed too?

I looked at querying the browsers local database to retrieve the users history but this doesn't store incognito data so this is no longer viable and i don't really want to go down this route and have different implementations for different browsers.

Any help, direction or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If such an API did exist *and* it bypassed incognito mode, wouldn't that mean that incognito mode was fundamentally broken? And bear in mind that not all browsers use OS functionality throughout (e.g. Windows XP never could talk TLS 1.1 but non-IE browsers were available that worked on XP and could talk TLS 1.1)

Comment: I don't think you have read my post correctly but for your information... Chrome stores the users history in sqlLite db locally that you can then query, obviously entries do not get added to the database when browsing in  incognito mode as this would defeat the point of... incognito browsing.

Comment: I read it as "I've looked at the browser DB but I can't use it since it doesn't contain incognito information" and my point was that if there's **anything** that's exposing incognito information then that would surely render incognito mode as fundamentally broken. So since you're (apparently) looking for something that does expose incognito information, I'm suggesting that it's unlikely to exist.

Comment: Your missing the point of the post you need to re-read the whole thing and not just the context of the one paragraph. Forget querying the browser db as i don't want to take this route. i'm asking is there another way to log urls without having to use a 3rd party packet sniffing library like winPcap or sharpPcap? or creating a proxy  and if so how do i go about doing it?